# UserRegistrationAPIView should either include a `querylist` attribute, or override the `get_querylist()` method

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views

am trying to create an API that would communicate with an android application, while trying to implement the user registration, i used the django custom User model, serialized it successfully but am kinda lost with the #app/Views codes 
and am quite new to django

```
class UserRegistrationAPIView(ObjectMultipleModelAPIView):
    def get_query_list(self):
        query_list = ({'queryset':      ClientUser.objects.all(),
                       'serializer_class':        UserClientRegSeerializer},
                      {'queryset': User.objects.all(),
                       'serializer_class': UserRegistrationSerializer}

                  )
        return query_list

class UserRegistrationAPIView(ObjectMultipleModelAPIView):

    def get_query_list(self):
        query_list = ({'queryset':      ClientUser.objects.all(),
                       'serializer_class':        UserClientRegSeerializer},
                      {'queryset': User.objects.all(),
                       'serializer_class': UserRegistrationSerializer}

                  )
        return query_list
```

Comment: It is `get_querylist`, not `get_query_list`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think he's using a third-party package named [**DjangoRestMultipleModels**](https://django-rest-multiple-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: @JPG: yes but as said, there is an underscore too much, it is `get_querylist`, not `get_query_list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://django-rest-multiple-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/object-options.html), you don't need to override any methods. All you need to do is, define an attribute named **`querylist`**.

```
class UserRegistrationAPIView(ObjectMultipleModelAPIView):
    querylist = [{'queryset': ClientUser.objects.all(),
                  'serializer_class': UserClientRegSeerializer},
                 {'queryset': User.objects.all(),
                  'serializer_class': UserRegistrationSerializer}

                 ]


class FooUserRegistrationAPIView(ObjectMultipleModelAPIView):
    querylist = [{'queryset': ClientUser.objects.all(),
                  'serializer_class': UserClientRegSeerializer},
                 {'queryset': User.objects.all(),
                  'serializer_class': UserRegistrationSerializer}

                 ]
```

**Note**: In your OP, you'd defined **`UserRegistrationAPIView`** class two time, which might be a mistake.